# JSONEncoder that ellides long lists

Tags: python, json, superclass

I want to dump some big JSON files, printing only the first few elements of each list. I am trying to write a custom encoder:

```
class EllidingEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def encode(self, obj):
        if isinstance(obj, list) and len(obj) > 6:
            return "[{:}, …]".format(", ".join([self.encode(i) for i in obj[:6]]))
        else:
            # The problem....
            return super(EllidingEncoder, self).encode(obj)
```

This kind of works:

```
$ json.dumps([i for i in range(7)], cls=EllidingEncoder)
> '[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, …]'
$ json.dumps([list([i for i in range(7)] for i in range(7)], cls=EllidingEncoder)
> '[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, …], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, …], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, …], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, …], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, …], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, …], …]'
```

But as soon as a list is contained in a dictionary, things break down:

```
$ json.dumps({i:[i for i in range(7)] for i in range(7)}, cls=EllidingEncoder)
> '{"0": [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], "1": [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], "2": [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], "3": [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], "4": [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], "5": [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], "6": [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]}'
```

Which makes sense, as JSONEncoder.encode has no way to know that it should call EllidingEncoder.encode.

I am starting to suspect that this simply cannot be done in this way. My workaround is to explicitly override also for dict's:

```
class EllidingEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def encode(self, obj):
        if isinstance(obj, list) and len(obj) > 6:
            return "[{:}, …]".format(", ".join([self.encode(i) for i in obj[:6]]))
        elif isinstance(obj, dict):
            return "{{{:}}}".format(", ".join(["{:} : {:}".format(k,self.encode(v)) for k,v in obj.items()]))
        else:
            return super(EllidingEncoder, self).encode(obj)
```

Any thoughts?

EDIT: Lists with more than 6 elements also need to be handled explicitly, of course!

```
class EllidingEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def encode(self, obj):
        if isinstance(obj, list):
            if len(obj) > 6:
                return "[{:}, …]".format(", ".join([self.encode(i) for i in obj[:6]]))
            else:
                return "[{:}]".format(", ".join([self.encode(i) for i in obj]))
        elif isinstance(obj, dict):
            return "{{{:}}}".format(", ".join(["{:} : {:}".format(k,self.encode(v)) for k,v in obj.items()]))
        else:
            return super(EllidingEncoder, self).encode(obj)
```

Comment: Customizing the output of any [Python objects](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.JSONEncoder) the `JSONEcoder` supports by default, is very difficult if not impossible in my experience. There are some tricks that can be played if you're able to wrap the input objects of interest in a "wrapper" class, but that's often not possible.

Comment: @Goyo thanks for pointing that out, fixed.